# How do I get this to write all of the films that are less than or equal to the users age?

Tags: c#, dictionary, foreach

I want my code to search through the "films" dictionary and output any films that have a rating less than the users age, however I am very new to c# and have little experience with dictionaries. Does anybody know a  way in which i could go about solving this? Would be greatly appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CinemaTing2._0
{
    class Program
    {
        public void Age(string[] args)
        {
            Dictionary<string, int> Films = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            //U rated films
            Films.Add("Shrek", 1);
            Films.Add("Finding Nemo", 1);
            Films.Add("A Bugs Life", 1);
            Films.Add("Flushed Away", 1);
            Films.Add("Charlie And The Chocolate Factory", 1);
            //PG films
            Films.Add("The Lion King", 2);
            Films.Add("Kung Fu Panda 3", 2);
            Films.Add("Puss In Boots", 2);
            Films.Add("Home Alone", 2);
            Films.Add("How To Train Your Dragon", 2);
            //12+ rated films
            Films.Add("Spider Man", 12);
            Films.Add("Sherlock Holmes", 12);
            Films.Add("War Horse", 12);
            Films.Add("Hunger Games", 12);
            Films.Add("Captain America", 12);
            //16+ rated films
            Films.Add("Forrest Gump", 15);
            Films.Add("Step Brothers", 15);
            Films.Add("Die Hard", 15);
            Films.Add("Saving Private Ryan", 15);
            Films.Add("The Matrix", 15);
            //18+ rated films
            Films.Add("RoboCop", 18);
            Films.Add("Mad Max 2", 18);
            Films.Add("Kill Bill", 18);
            Films.Add("Predator", 18);
            Films.Add("Dawn Of The Dead", 18);

            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to my cinema booking system. Please enter your age: ");
            int i = 1;
            int userAge = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            while (i == 1)
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> item in Films)
                {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linq is a great tool to learn for interacting with Lists, Dictionaries etc.

There is a `.Where()` method which will search through the collection and apply a condition on every record.

You'll need to include the using statement `using System.Linq;`

The following statement:
`Films.Where(record => record.Value <= 12)` means search through all the dictionary records and return me a list of records whose value is less than or equal to 12.

In your case, 12 will be a variable which will be the users age.

We can then loop through this list and process as required.

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> film in Films.Where(record => record.Value <= 12))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Film: {film.Key}");
}
```

https://repl.it/repls/DizzyCheeryAlphatest